Le doppie nell'accento milanese
Nel quadro di questa domanda consideriamo il nostro modello dell'accento milanese quello di Berlusconi da questo video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L33cHe68wFM
Il secondo assunto sarà che in questo accento le doppie sono pronunciate "differentemente" dalla pronuncia "standard". Alcuni dicono che le doppie sono pronunciate come consonanti singole. Io direi piuttosto che sono pronunciate come "una consonante e mezzo", anche se a volte sento infatti una consonante singola.
Consideriamo adesso le parole che hanno due paia di consonanti doppie, tra cui uno è accentato. Berlusconi le pronuncia in questo video:

addirittura 5:36
soprattutto 7:50

Mi chiedo se entrambe le paia - accentate e non accentate - sono pronunciate nello stesso modo nell'accento milanese. Non sono sicuro se è la doppia che è pronunciata differentemente oppure è la vocale nella sillaba tonica che fa questo effetto all'orecchio.
